# Socket AsyncTask does not log the socket.isConnected value in the code

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have the following code in order to execute a asynchronous task in android in order to connect to a socket.

call to the asynctask is

```
new SocketAsyncTask().execute("abc");
```

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private static String connectionURL ="MY_URL" ;
private static int port = 3000;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... uri) {
     try {
         String sentence;
         String modifiedSentence;
         Socket clientSocket = new Socket(connectionURL, port);
         Log.d("In socket",clientSocket.isConnected() + "");

         if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
             Log.d("Client connection Successfull!!", "true");
             //System.out.print("Connection Successfull!!");
         } else {
             //System.out.print("Connection Not Successfull!!");
             Log.d("Client connection not Successfull!!", "true");
         }
        /*DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);*/
         clientSocket.close();
     }catch (IOException exp) {

     }
 return null;
}
```

}

The output does print the "In socket" string however, it does not log either "Client connection successfull" or "Client connection not successfull". I tried debugging it but it basically does something weird. It prints the "In socket" in logcat but does not seem to stop at that breakpoint.

Comment: Then it's probably throwing and exception. Add log statement to your catch block.

Comment: Have you specified the internet uses-permission in the manifest?!??

Comment: Yes @aorlando I have added the internet uses-permission.

Answer (score 1):

There no point in logging `isConnected()` in the first place. If the constructor didn't throw an exception, the socket *is* connected. The `isConnected()` test cannot possibly be false at the point where you're testing it.

The problem here is that you're ignoring the exception, which you should be logging.

Comment: yes, sure an exception; also a simple connection refused

Comment: @aorlando You can't know that. Could be unknown host, no route, ... I also note that he's using a URL where he should be using a hostname.

Comment: it was an example of exception ... and he is not using an URL he is using a string and in the string it is mandatory to specify an hostname or an InetAddress type